# Are cover diagrams and Hasse diagrams the same thing?

Tags: order-theory

I am making some [notes on my blog](https://galenseilis.github.io/posts/notes-on-order-theory/) about order theory. In [this lecture](https://youtu.be/WsQyp7lU6O4?list=PL5rqYzyihIQ0nzfnsEKxxedCpbNQoifgg&t=1162) the instructor presents a "cover diagram" based on a cover relation. Because my notes are entirely digital and I have never drawn such figures before I have asked about [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) for drawing cover diagrams in [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/157692/algorithm-for-finding-an-embedding-of-a-cover-diagram). But I also noticed that a [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) looks highly-similar, and I am wondering if they are the same.

Are Hasse diagrams the same thing as cover diagrams?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: The thing he calls "the diagram" (as opposed to "the cover graph") is the Hasse diagram, yes.